# Line Count for a function

Tags: c++

I have to take the following function  and code it up so as it runs, it calculates its own line count. I'm just wondering if its possible to do this on code and have the number stored in an int lineCount? I heard something about using a #predefined Macro called **Count**?

Comment: `it calculates its own line count`: I doubt it does...

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to say "I heard something about X", consider if you can say where you heard it. If you can't do that, keep quiet about it.

Comment: Regarding `Count`: The Muppet API was deprecated after Henson died. On the less flip side, [you are probably thinking `__COUNTER__`.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: I seem to recall that there is a preprocessor value, __LINE__, that specifies the current line.  You could create a macro that stores the count at the beginning of the function and another that subtracts the first at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you mean that `it calculates its own line count` means that it's counting how many times the innermost loop works.

You can do something like this:

```
typedef double Matrix[100][100];

int multiply(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C, int n){
    int count = 0;
    //n is the actual matrix order
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k){
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: So  every statement that reoccurs is being counted as an executed line of code? Kinda feel silly if true.

Comment: @Marco No idea if true or not. Simply going off an assumption in case it might be what is needed.